# C or C++ programming with contikiOS on Arduino Due

Tags: c, arduino, rtos, contiki

What I need to do is to compile and run a program written in C/C++ on Arduino.

I'm ok with every open source RTOS if it supports C especially struct.

So I have found contikiOS does that, and tried to get started.

But I guess contikiOS doesn't support Arduino port anymore and Due is quite recent model so that I couldn't find proper information.

If you know any information on it or want me to help, please give me an advice.
Ah, do you have any other recommendation for RTOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you need is to run a simple c/c++ software, you have to know that the arduino environment support c/c++ code, as explained in the arduino homepage http://code.google.com/p/arduino/
If for your **requirements**, you need to use a real time operating system, there is a contikiOS version for Arduino (Contiki-Arduino).

Last but not least, if you are a beginner, i would advice you to use a popular RTOS, to find support on internet easily if you need it. Sadly, i am not an expert on that field. But when i google it, i find Duinos, maybe you could have a look on it.